# How to layer statistics from Excel onto a map?

Tags: web-mapping, excel, thematic-map

Would another free app or program be better and easier to do this than mapbox.com ?

I simply want to layer census 2010 data by shading areas onto a map like on [theatlanticcities.com/posts/map/](http://theatlanticcities.com/posts/map/) & [developmentseed.org](http://developmentseed.org).

Comment: Contrary to what you claim, comments to the closed question indicate what (some of) the problems with it were.  Our [faq] gives you some guidance for asking answerable questions that are on topic.

Answer (score 2):

Excel can hold the attribute values, but doesn't manage the boundaries (the shapes of the census districts).

I haven't used MapBox before, but a quick look suggests it's only applicable for points (rather than polygon boundaries).

To store and server census information onto a web map, you'll probably want some kind of spatial server. Free options include [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome) and [Google Fusion Tables](http://support.google.com/fusiontables/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2571232), which can store and serve KML files.

You'll need a viewer with the ability to display the polygons and their attributes. Free options include [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) and [Leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/), and of course the [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) API.

An alternative to using a spatial server is to store the census boundaries in GeoJSON. There's a nice example on the Leaflet site [here](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/examples/geojson.html).

There's a good introduction to some popular free GIS programs available on the [OpenGeo site](http://workshops.opengeo.org/stack-intro/).

Comment: where do you get the "polygon boundaries" data? after you get it, it sounds like you put them in  GeoJSON and then use "OpenLayers and Leaflet, and of course the Google Maps API." to display them.

Comment: none of this says how to take the data from excel and put them onto a map. what are the steps? doesn't have to be a web map.

Comment: Fair enough - I assumed some knowledge of GIS, since this is a GIS-specific site. You may need to look into [GIS basics](http://www.esri.com/what-is-gis/index.html) to get started. See [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) for a free desktop GIS. You'll need to source the census data from somewhere (which city/country are you in?) and likely perform some processing. You'll need to [join](http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/join_csv.php) the attributes from Excel to the polygon boundaries, so that the values from Excel can be displayed spatially.

Comment: instead of making a new question thread, i'll ask here: is there any easy way to dl the "shapefile" or "boundaries" from zipmaps.net/California/San_Francisco_County/Z_Downtown.htm -- for the census data, i eventually want to do the world, but right now -- gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32797/how-to-download-all-census-2010-statistics-onto-postgresql-postgis

Comment: can you layer the statistics onto google earth?

Comment: you could also have linked  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31316/how-to-put-zipcodes-data-onto-a-map as one of the first link or maybe even http://workshops.opengeo.org/stack-intro/ as the first one

Comment: The "how to map zipcodes" link is very thorough and should answer your questions

Comment: yes it covers a lot of basics in a easy to comprehend manner unlike other sources of info so i had edited the question title to make that thread more find-able/visible

Comment: It is advisable to open another thread if you do have another question and not ask on the comments. That way, other people can learn from your question, too.